# Undefined index - How to isset correctly?

Tags: php

Have this function, with the member email echo returning an undefined index. How do I isset this the proper way?

```
function team_custom_columns( $column ) {
    global $post;
    switch ( $column )
    {

        case 'member_email':
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            echo $custom['member_email_address'][0];
            break;
        case 'member_description':
            the_content();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use !empty() method before echo custom post index

```
function team_custom_columns( $column ) {
    global $post;
    switch ( $column )
    {

        case 'member_email':
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            if(!empty($custom['member_email_address'][0]))
                echo $custom['member_email_address'][0];
            break;
        case 'member_description':
            the_content();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Both great answers, and work well.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ternary Operator:

```
echo isset($custom['member_email_address'][0])
     ? $custom['member_email_address'][0]
     : 'not set';
```

Or If:

```
if (isset($custom['member_email_address'][0])) {
    // value exists
} else {
    // not set
}
```